# drush not finding correct multisite settings.php

Tags: drush, multi-sites

I have a Drupal 9 site using multisite to support both local and production hosts. I have defined them in sites/sites.php:

```
$sites['www.electronovelty.com'] = 'www.electronovelty.com';
$sites['www.en9-local.pglatz.com'] = 'www.en9-local.pglatz.com';
```

and created settings files in

```
sites/www.electronovelty.com/settings.php
sites/www.en9-local.pglatz.com/settings.php
```

Using xdebug, I've verified when opening the two web sites that the correct settings.php is used. But when I try to run drush 11, it is using settings from sites/default/settings.php for some reason:

```
% drush cr -v                            
 [info] Starting bootstrap to site
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase 2
 [info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 2
 [info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 2
 [info] Try to bootstrap at phase 2
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalRoot()
 [info] Change working directory to /Users/pglatz/dev/electronovelty/en9-www/web
 [info] Initialized Drupal 9.3.12 root directory at /Users/pglatz/dev/electronovelty/en9-www/web
 [info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 2
 [info] Try to bootstrap at phase 2
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalSite()
 [info] Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default
 [success] Cache rebuild complete.
```

I tried specifying the uri, and it finds the correct settings.php, but I'm also getting a "command nt found" error, which I do not understand:

```
% drush -l www.en9-local.pglatz.com -v cr
 [info] Starting bootstrap to site
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase 2
 [info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 2
 [info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 2
 [info] Try to bootstrap at phase 2
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalRoot()
 [info] Change working directory to /Users/pglatz/dev/electronovelty/en9-www/web
 [info] Initialized Drupal 9.3.12 root directory at /Users/pglatz/dev/electronovelty/en9-www/web
 [info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 2
 [info] Try to bootstrap at phase 2
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalSite()
 [info] Initialized Drupal site www.en9-local.pglatz.com at sites/www.en9-local.pglatz.com
sh: ^www.en9-local.pglatz.com$: command not found
 [success] Cache rebuild complete.
```

Where is that error coming from, and what does it mean?

Comment: Could be a shell expansion issue - try putting the URL in quotes

Comment: +1 you have to escape or quote certain characters in certain shells, notably '-'.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried double and single quotes on the url in the command line, also tried escaping the - but have the same issue. Also tried --uri= instead of -w. So this is a shell issue, from the command line, rather than something internal to drush? I'm own a Mac, using zsh, but I get a similar error on my remote using ubuntu and bash.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to handle this:

1. Use the `-l` flag with your drush command: `drush -l  www.electronovelty.com cr`
2. Create a drush alias, and call the alias. To create aliases, you can create the file /drush/sites/self.site/yml, and put the following contents:

   ```
    site1:
      uri: www.en9-local.pglatz.com
    site2:
      uri: www.electronovelty.com
   ```

   You can then use the aliases:

   ```
    drush @site1 cr
    drush @site2 cr
   ```

   And the relevant multisite will be called.

Comment: Thanks. I did try `-l `in my second example. I just created a site alias and am still getting the `sh: ^www.en9-local.pglatz.com$: command not found` warning.

Comment: Seems weird that you are getting a shell error for a drush command. Are you running this in a shell script?

Comment: Anyways, if you are getting this error, it means you've introduced a bug somewhere into your system with some contributed or custom code. The suggestions I gave work in a default Drupal mutlisite with Drush 11, so if you are getting an error, it's specific to your system.

Comment: thanks, I'll investigate some more